# PHP 5.3.24 on UBUNTU14 problems

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, php-5.3

I have tried to 'make' an install of php 5.3.24 on my UBUNTU14 server with no success.

```
tar -xvf php-5.3.24.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.24
./configure
make
make install
```

Everything seems to work, but I dont think the connectors for php5-mysql are loaded.

Is there any distribution source I can add for php5.3.24 to APT-GET so I can do an install that way.

I have found really old versions such as 5.2.13.. but I need to be as close to 5.3.24 without going over as possible,

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have to use this version as any higher, the ancient website I am trying to migrate just dies horribly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a program that allows multiple versions of PHP, I was then able to compile over versions of PHP using the libraries that came with the program